# Multiple definitions error: How to declare a reference in a header file?

Tags: c++, qt, reference, header

```
qtGUI.o:(.bss+0x0): multiple definition of `R'
rWidgetPlots.o:(.bss+0x0): first defined here
qtGUI.o:(.rodata+0x0): multiple definition of `qtToR'
rWidgetPlots.o:(.rodata+0x0): first defined here
main.o:(.bss+0x0): multiple definition of `R'
rWidgetPlots.o:(.bss+0x0): first defined here
main.o:(.rodata+0x0): multiple definition of `qtToR'
rWidgetPlots.o:(.rodata+0x0): first defined here
moc_qtGUI.o:(.bss+0x0): multiple definition of `R'
rWidgetPlots.o:(.bss+0x0): first defined here
moc_qtGUI.o:(.rodata+0x40): multiple definition of `qtToR'
rWidgetPlots.o:(.rodata+0x0): first defined here
```

**rWidgetPlots.h**

```
#ifndef RWIDGETPLOTSH
#define RWIDGETPLOTSH

#include <iostream>
#include <RInside.h>
#include <Rcpp.h>
#include <vector>
#include <limits>
#include <QRect>
#include <fstream>
#include "zoomAndCornerDatabaseParser.h"

RInside R (0, NULL);
RInside & qtToR (R);

typedef struct
{
        double       latitude;
        double       longitude;
        unsigned int vehicleId;
} vehicle;

extern std :: vector <vehicle> vehicleInfo;

typedef struct
{
    float latitude;
    float longitude;
} coordinate;

extern std :: vector <coordinate> previousPoints;

class rdaTilesOnR
{
    public:
        static std :: string returnCenterPoint    (std :: string fileName);
        static std :: string findPanningDirection (float newLatitude, float newLongitude,
                        std :: string topLeftLat, std :: string topLeftLng, 
                        std :: string northEastLat, std :: string northEastLng, 
                    std :: string bottomRightLat, std :: string bottomRightLng, 
                    std :: string southWestLat, std :: string southWestLng);

        static void storeVehicleInfo  (float latitude, float longitude, unsigned int vehicleId);

        static void loadNewTileAndPlotPointsOnRWidget (unsigned short option, float newLongitude, float newLatitude);

        static std :: string doesPointLieInBoundaries  (unsigned short option, float newLatitude, float newLongitude, float currentCenterLatitude, float currentCenterLongitude);
};

#endif
```

**qtGUI.h**

```
#ifndef QTGUIH
#define QTGUIH

#include <QApplication>
#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QtCore>
#include <QtGui>
#include <QPushButton>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>

#include "rWidgetPlots.h"

class controlRThroughQt : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT  

    QTextEdit  *textEdit;

    public:
        void qtInterface ();

    public slots:
        void slotPanLeft     ();
        void slotPanRight   ();
        void slotPanTop      ();
        void slotPanBottom ();
        void slotZoomIn      ();
        void slotZoomOut    ();
        void slotRefresh      ();
        void findInfoByClicking ();
};

#endif
```

**`qtToR` here is a reference. It has to defined then and there. How to resolve this error?** Using `extern` doesn't help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> It has to defined then and there.

Well then, it can't be done. If you're willing to leave this in the header:

```
extern RInside R;
extern RInside & qtToR;
```

and move the definition to a single implementation file:

```
//somecpp.cpp
RInside R (0, NULL);
RInside & qtToR (R);
```

that'd do it.

Comment: AH, I didn't know that extern could be used w.r.t references also! Thanks, that helped.